# Trying to store Data in android using SQLite , problems in creating contract class and helper class

Tags: java, android

heres a screenshot https://ibb.co/Yjvy3Z7
basically showing that cant resolve SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES even though i created it in another class
i defined it in the subclass of the feeder contract class .I know that you just can expect to share variables in between classess like that but what am i supposed to do now ? the documentation did say about some other things but oh well...

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class FeedReaderContract {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // make the constructor private.
    private FeedReaderContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "relapse_data";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "Name"; //text
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY = "Quantity"; //integer
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CHOCOLATE = "Chocolate"; //integer 0-false 1 -true
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WHIPPED_CREAM = "Whipped Cream";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COST = "Cost"; //integer
        public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
                COLUMN_NAME_NAME+" TEXT,"+
                COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY+" INTEGER,"+
                COLUMN_NAME_CHOCOLATE+" INTEGER,"+
                COLUMN_NAME_WHIPPED_CREAM+" INTEGER,"+
                COLUMN_NAME_COST+" INTEGER"
                +")";

    }
}
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
//    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
//        // to simply to discard the data and start over
//        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
//        onCreate(db);
//    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: I recomment you read about room framework for android. I find it an easier way to work with sqlite on android and it avoids some errors and typos in sql as it even evaluates some of your sql while coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct version of your code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class FeedReaderContract {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // make the constructor private.
    private FeedReaderContract() {
    }

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "relapse_data";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "Name"; //text
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY = "Quantity"; //integer
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CHOCOLATE = "Chocolate"; //integer 0-false 1 -true
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WHIPPED_CREAM = "Whipped Cream";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COST = "Cost"; //integer
        public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_NAME_NAME + "TEXT," +
                COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY + "INTEGER," +
                COLUMN_NAME_CHOCOLATE + "INTEGER," +
                COLUMN_NAME_WHIPPED_CREAM + "INTEGER," +
                COLUMN_NAME_COST + " INTEGER"
                + ")";

    }
}

class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //KEEP IT EMPTY INSTEAD OF COMMENTING
    }

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onDowngrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Here you go!